# Import Hotmail contacts "the right way"?

Tags: live, contacts, hotmail

I have a website where I want to allow the users to invite their friends, by getting their contacts in hotmail/msn.

Google has the google contacts API for these purposes, does MSN publish a similar javascript API?

Please note that I do *not* want to ask the user for their username/password like http://openinviter.com/ .

Also, if anyone can provide some tutorials / examples I would appreciate it, as Microsoft docs are usually hard to understand :)

Comment: I believe this was wrongly closed. The question is not subjective, it asks how to retrieve the contacts with some sort of API or oficial interconnection. The title may be bad but the message content clearly states what is being asked.