# Import Hotmail Contacts

Tags: php, web-services, integration, hotmail

I am trying to allow users to import their Hotmail contacts to my site to invite friends. I am looking to write a custom PHP solution, not something like http://openinviter.com/. I tried the Live API, but it only outputs email hashes.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? It was super easy to setup on Yahoo! and Gmail, but Hotmail has me floored. I need this to work on PHP 5.3.

Comment: Have you tried looking at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489622/import-hotmail-contacts-the-right-way? It has a lot of suggestions (also ones that support php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went with a work around / solution that requires the user to copy and past the "Print View" of their entire address book from Hotmail. Then I scrape the textarea input for email addresses using a regex statement.

While it is not ideal, it does work and my users don't seem to mind the copying and pasting since it is just one Copy/Paste for the entire address book. So far my users have imported 700 email addresses using this method and I have not received any bug reports or complaints about the work around I used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you looked at [this](http://livecontactsphp.codeplex.com/) and it didn't help you at all?

EDIT: looking at [Windows Live Messenger Connect Reference, Version 5.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243650.aspx) it appears that if you can navigate your way around their [OAuth 2.0 implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243647.aspx) there is a fairly reasonable [REST api for Contact access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243648.aspx#contact). Is this what you've been arguing with? There's a question at [Retrieving user profile on messenger(windows live) connect sdk within php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526808/retrieving-user-profile-on-messengerwindows-live-connect-sdk-within-php) that discusses the sample code at http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/messengerconnect/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4595. Given that you're offering a bounty I'll assume that you've already run this gauntlet, so I'll ask: have you gotten the OAuth to work at all, or are you still stuck there?

Comment: I have looked in to your update too. If you look closely on the REST Contacts page, you will see it only outputs email hashes used for matching, no actual email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft's documentation: [Finding People Who a User Knows on a Website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/hh278351)

Comment: That is not what I am looking for. I am trying to import a users contacts into my site. Not match them with people already on my site.